# dbus launching error! when booting ARM linux via NFS

Tags: linux, filesystems, embedded-linux, dbus, nfs

Attempting to compile D-Bus for ARM but encountering an error.

I use NFS to boot ARM board and load file-system from a directory "/home/make/root_nfs" on PC.

1. Building D-Bus from sources on PC(ubuntu10.10):

   > `./configure  --prefix=/home/make/dbus --exec-prefix=/home/make/dbus CC="arm-linux-gcc"  --host=arm-linux  --with-x=no --cache-file=arm-linux.cache`
   >
   > `make`
   >
   > `make install`
2. Copying D-Bus's bins, libs and other dependencies from "/home/make/dbus" into their corresponding directories under "/home/make/root_nfs/".
3. Rebooting the ARM board to load the root fs from my host PC "/home/make/root_nfs".
4. In arm linux:

   Trying: `dbus-launch`

   *Failed to execute message bus daemon /home/make/dbus/bin/dbus-daemon: No such file or directory.  Will try again without full path.*

   *Failed to start message bus: Failed to open "/home/make/dbus/etc/dbus-1/session.conf: No such file or directory*
   *EOF in dbus-launch reading address from bus daemon*

   Trying: `dbus-daemon --system`

   *Failed to start message bus: Failed to open "/home/make/dbus/etc/dbus-1/system.conf": No such file or directory*

**It seems that all the Path's have been hardcoded into program.**

**Changing "--prefix" or "--exec-prefix" in configuration of D-Bus does not work.**

I do not want to "mkdir -p /home/make/root_nfs/home/make/root_nfs" on PC and make the arm linux treat the second level root_nfs as correct path.

Can anyone give some suggestions?

*Thanks a lot.*

Answer (score 0):

configure --prefix and --exec-prefix option are usually use to configure path for **runtime**

You have to use [**DESTDIR**](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/DESTDIR.html) parameter for make:

```
./configure CC="arm-linux-gcc" --host=arm-linux --with-x=no --cache-file=arm-linux.cache
make
make DESTDIR=/home/make/dbus install
```